# Unable to properly do a While Loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a while loop. I have been trying for a long time, but still cannot figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char input;
double voltage, current;

while ((input = 'Y'))
{
    cout << "Enter the voltage: ";
    cin >> voltage;
    cout << "Enter the current: ";
    cin >> current;

    cout << "The resistance is " << voltage/current << endl;

    cout << "Do you wish to continue? [Y/N]";
    cin >> input;
}
}
```

Entering other variables other than 'Y' still causes the code to loop. Doing //while ((input == 'Y')) does not give me an output

Comment: Try `while ((input == 'Y'))`.

Comment: And while you're at it, maybe initialize `input` to something besides ether. Right now you have (in theory) a 1/256 chance your loop will actually be entered after fixing your assignment typo. Not good odds.

Comment: Let me guess: The compiler gave you a warning, that `while (input = y)` is probably not what you want and insted of correcting the problem you chose to suppress the warning by adding a second set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that the *first* time you enter  the loop, `input` has no value. This can be fixed by giving it an initial value in its declaration

```
int main()
{
char input = 'Y';
double voltage, current;

while (input == 'Y')
{
```

You then still have the problem that the user might enter `'y'` instead of `'Y'` at the end of the loop. We'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Ironically, that double-paran around the assignment in the while condition suggests the OP either knew, or the compiler warned, that was an assignment and surrounding it with an extra set of parens would squelch the warning. That probably should have been the first clue something was wrong.

Comment: Alternatively, use a `do {} while ()` loop, which advertises to the reader that the loop will always execute at least once.